# FluentValidator custom Password is stopping at the first rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidator in an MVC project to validate view model passwords so this is my class:

```
namespace example123.Models
{
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterModel>
    {
        public RegisterValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Email)
                .NotNull()
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Email is required")
                .EmailAddress()
                .WithMessage("Invalid email format");

            RuleFor(a => a.Password).Password();
        }
    }
}
```

So I created a custom rule and extended the rule with:

```
public static class RuleBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> Password<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder, int minimumLength = 8)
        {
            var options = ruleBuilder
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required")
                .MinimumLength(minimumLength).WithMessage("Length")
                .Matches("[A-Z]").WithMessage("Uppercase msg")
                .Matches("[a-z]").WithMessage("Lowercase msg")
                .Matches("[0-9]").WithMessage("Digit msg")
                .Matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").WithMessage("Sepcial char msg");
            return options;
        }
    }
```

Rendered Html code:

```
 <input type="password" class="form-control input-validation-error validate-equalTo-blur" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" data-val="true" data-val-minlength="Password must be at least 6 characters long" data-val-minlength-min="6" data-val-regex="Uppercase" data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Z]" data-val-required="Password is required" id="Password" name="Password" aria-describedby="Password-error" aria-invalid="true">
```

The view Register.cshtml is using default jQuery-validate implementation that comes in default **MVC** project. Email is working fine but **the password is stopping at the "Uppercase" rule [A-Z]** and is not going away, other custom messages are not displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you set a default cascade behavior for validation rules?

Comment: @GregBurghardt - No I didn't set a cascade behavior for any rule.

Comment: I wonder if the default cascade behavior is the reason. Does FluentValidation support multiple regular expressions on a single property? Does jQuery validate support multiple regex's on a single form field? Can you post the rendered HTML for the password field in your question?

Comment: Try writing some unit tests for your validator in C#. That might help pinpoint the failure.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I saw this form of validation in some other questions where it worked on Web API Project but not in MVC. FluentValidation accepts multiple regular expressions on a single property. The problem may be with jquery-validation which is integrated in the default MVC project, and I do not know anything about jquery and how it works.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the rendered HTML for the password field? I think your suspicion might be correct and the jquery validate plugin.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I just edited it, or you can see it as a screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/6iIZD6p.png

Comment: The regular excursions in the question don't make sense to me either. Can you explain what the rules are for passwords? They must have an upper case, a lower case and at least one digit?

Comment: And a special character?

Comment: @GregBurghardt - yes, one lowercase, one uppercase, one digit, and special char, all these rules must have a special message.

Comment: I don't know if you can accomplish this with a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

So I am included a bunch of different options that might meet your needs.

Are you opposed to using the Must method of FluentValidation? If so it can look something like this:

Create a validation method:

```
private bool ValidatePassword(string pw)
{
    var lowercase = new Regex("[a-z]+");
    var uppercase = new Regex("[A-Z]+");
    var digit = new Regex("(\\d)+");
    var symbol = new Regex("(\\W)+");

    return (lowercase.IsMatch(pw) && uppercase.IsMatch(pw) && digit.IsMatch(pw) && symbol.IsMatch(pw));
}
```

Then create the rule where you did your email one.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Password)
            .Length(5, 15)
            .Must(HasValidPassword);
    }
```

And if you have a confirm password field you can do this too:

```
RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
    .Equal(x => x.Password)
    .WithMessage("Passwords must match");
```

I believe the main issue is that you are doing this in an extensions which fluentvalidation can consider custom and not built-in, so it might run into some problems.

Only other thing I noticed is you could try changing:

```
.Matches("[A-Z]").WithMessage("Uppercase msg")
```

to

```
.Matches(@"[A-Z]+").WithMessage("Your password must contain at least one uppercase letter.")
.Matches(@"[a-z]+").WithMessage("Your password must contain at least one lowercase letter.")
 .Matches(@"[0-9]+").WithMessage("Your password must contain at least one number.")
 .Matches(@"[\!\?\*\.]+").WithMessage("Your password must contain at least one (!? *.).");
```

I added the @ and + for regex regular expression. That might help you too.

Not sure if fluentvalidation cares about the plus sign, but try taking it out of the extension method and doing a normal rule like you did for email and see if that solves it.

If you are trying to do client-side validation then I am pretty sure this won't work. The way you have it currently I believe is for server-side validation and not client. You could just use jQuery directly in the client too and that might meet your need for clien-side. Here is a quick example:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("passwordCheck",
        function(value, element, param) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            } else if (!/[A-Z]/.test(value)) {
                return false;
            } else if (!/[a-z]/.test(value)) {
                return false;
            } else if (!/[0-9]/.test(value)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        },
        "error msg here");
```

and then attach it to attribute on view:

```
<input type="password" id="RegisterModel_Password" 
name="RegisterModel.Password" 
class="form-control" 
required="required" minlength="8" 
passwordCheck="passwordCheck"/>
```

Comment: The point is that I want the messages to be specific and not just a single message like "Password needs to be complex". I also tried to add @ and + but it still stops at the first rule. The problem seems to be entirely at jquery-validate. :(

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and wrote the following little xUnit test:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData("hello", false)]
[InlineData("helloworld", false)]
[InlineData("HelloWorld", false)]
[InlineData("HelloWorld1", false)]
[InlineData("HelloWorld1!", true)]
public void TestName(string password, bool expectedValidity)
{
    // Arrange
    var testee = new RegisterValidator();

    // Act
    var result = testee.Validate(new RegisterModel{Email = "bla@blub.com", Password = password});

    // Assert
    result.IsValid.Should().Be(expectedValidity);
}
```

All the tests are passing on my machine. So could you please check whether one of the test cases fails on your machine? If not, there must be a problem with the client logic (e. g. missing refresh).

Comment: Then the problem should be with jquery-validation which is integrated by default in the MVC project of ASP.NET Core. and I do not know anything about jquery and how it works.